# Confusion with [gml] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [gml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml) tag's wiki explains that it is for the *Game Maker Language*:

> Game Maker Language (GML) is an interpreted scripting language developed for use with a computer game creation application called Game Maker.

However, quite often , I see this tag used for [*Geography Markup Language*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_Markup_Language).
  I do not know anything about Geography Markup Language or have enough rep on SO to create new tags, but it would be helpful if someone who did could create a new tag for it.

Comment: Agreed. There is the [tag:game-maker] tag, so [tag:gml] tag should be reserved for geography markup language, IMHO.

Comment: Or, you know, have [game-maker] and [geography-markup] tags and remove [gml]

Comment: @Braiam: shouldn't it be the answer? :) however, I'd suggest [tag:gml-game-maker] and [tag:gml-geography-language] or something like that, since I think many people will probably quickly write `gml` in the tags and they will not notice that there is something like `game-maker`

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl I agree, best start both tags with `gml`.

Comment: I work with the Geographic version, which is a dialect of XML for encoding vectors/geometries (among other things). Over half of the 111 entries tagged with gml would appear to be about the geo not the game maker language. I have created the tag geography-markup as only 25 characters are allowed. I would have preferred to use gml-geography-markup-language, however, I fear people from these two distinct areas will continue to use gml as a tag, as to them, that is what it means. If it gets approved, I will edit all the questions which are geographic to use this new tag.

Comment: OK; that was stupid. I should have used gml-geography-markup. Can anyone with more privileges than me override/edit my tag creation?

Comment: @JohnBarça: Mixed news: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag - but surely that is a "no-brainer" case. For now, I think the best way would be now to just create the `gml-xxx` versions. Maybe leave `geography-markup` and mark it as "suggested synonym" for correct gml-xxx tag? This however "requires at least 5 score in that category" so I'm unable to do so

Comment: @quetzalcoatl. OK, I have fixed that and am going through all the questions and updating any tags that are geo in nature to gml-geographic-markup-lan. In so doing, I have found yet another meaning of gml, graph modelling language, in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918791/convert-gml-file-to-adjacency-matrix-in-matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the GML that relates to the geographic, so I have created a tag [gml-geographic-markup-lan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml-geographic-markup-lan) and am slowly going through the 111 questions that were tagged with gml and retagging the geographic ones and removing the gml tag, while leaving those relating to Game Maker Language as gml. I went with Quetazcoatl's suggestion to have the tag start with gml, as I think if you are used to calling something gml, you are less likely to find it if you have to start by typing graph, game of geography instead.

While doing this, I discovered yet another, gml, namely `Graph Modelling Language`, so I created a tag for that too.

I know that for those of use who use GML, the geographic version, we refer to it as GML, and I have to confess, if I were to tag a question with GML, until yesterday, I wouldn't have thought twice about that fact that another language has already taken that tag -- how often do you read the tag definition when tagging something with javascript, SQL, PHP (you get the point), and none of the 3 GMLs I have discovered are exactly mainstream. I don't know how many other technologies share a common abbreviation like this, but it is worth bearing in mind.

Comment: Some technologies sharing GML abbreviation -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GML