# GML tag confusion--still unclear

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

This topic was [already addressed before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283385/gml-tag-confusion/), but it's still not really solved.

The tag [gml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml) is per definition used for the GameMaker Language. But browsing through the tag, I often see questions about the Geographic Markup Language. [The Wikipedia disambiguation page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GML) lists a few other languages with the same abbreviation. I re-tagged the first few questions I saw but the problem of wrong tagged questions persists.

Everything that uses GameMaker Language also uses the GameMaker, which has its own tag, [game-maker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-maker). Questions about the GameMaker that don't deal with the GameMaker Language usually don't belong to Stack Overflow, but maybe to gamedev.stackexchange, except questions that deal with embedding GameMaker games in other environments. I think we can merge [gml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml) into [game-maker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-maker). The [gml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml) tag should be reserved for the Geographic Markup Language since it seems to be the most used GML language.

Comment: *"...we can merge [tag:gml] into [tag:game-maker]. The [tag:gml] tag should be reserved for the Geographic Markup Language..."* - those two things are mutually exclusive!

Answer (score -1):

I think this should be handled by:

1. removing the [gml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml) from all questions with [game-maker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-maker)
2. editing the tag wiki for [gml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml) to reference the Geographic Markup Language instead

Comment: There is already a tag [gml-geographic-markup-lan] created that Geographic Markup Language should be re-tagged too.

Comment: That's what I meant. Sorry if I was unclear.