# Synonym proposal: [gml] -> [game-maker-language]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Both [game-maker-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-maker-language) and [gml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml) are tags for the Game Maker scripting language developed for use with the Game Maker tool.

[game-maker-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-maker-language) has 128 questions and a tag wiki of

> General Game Maker Language (GML) support. The programming language used in Game Maker and Game Maker: Studio.

[gml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml) has 333 questions and a tag wiki of

> Game Maker Language (GML) is an interpreted scripting language developed for use with a computer game creation application called Game Maker. Use this tag only for questions about language features, or requiring code in Game Maker Language. For questions relating to Geography Markup Language, use the [gml-geographic-markup-lan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml-geographic-markup-lan) tag instead. For Graph Markup Language, see the [graphml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphml) tag.

There is also a [game-maker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-maker) tag which has 456 questions and a tag wiki of

> GameMaker is a Windows and Mac OS IDE which allows users to easily develop computer games without the requirement of prior computer programming experience.

[game-maker-studio-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-maker-studio-2) also exists with 199 questions, and a tag wiki of

> GameMaker Studio 2 (often called GMS2) is a 2D game development IDE. It is the next iteration of GameMaker: Studio, developed and published by YoYo Games. Use this tag only if your question relates to IDE operation, features and game development in GameMaker Studio 2.

A discussion about the [gml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml) tag  [happened in 2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283385/confusion-with-gml-tag) which sorted out the [gml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gml) tag confusion, but didnt cover the multiple Gamemaker tags

Comment: I'd suggest that [[tag:game-maker-language]] is the better tag here; it's unlikely to end up being an ambiguous tag in the future, should another product have the same acronym. It seems there has been confusion with [[tag:graphml]] in the past, so this only cements the point. So [[tag:gjm]] should be made a synonym of [[tag:game-maker-language]] instead.

Comment: "A discussion about the gml tag happened in 2015 **which sorted out the gml tag confusion**, but didnt cover the multiple Gamemaker tags" Looking at the Q&A, that's not how I would summarise it. Especially the answer acknowledges that the TLA GML is misleading and likely to be misused. This rather suggests that [tag:gml] should not exist, neither by itself nor as a synonym.

Comment: @ThomA sounds worthy of an answer post to me.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Normally I would tend to agree, but in this case the asker has agreed with the suggestion and edited that into the question (I assume "[gjm]" is a typo of "[gml]").

Comment: *Game Maker* or *GameMaker*? I think it is *GameMaker* always. For example, [this says](https://manual.gamemaker.io/monthly/en/GameMaker_Language.htm) *"GameMaker Language"*

Comment: @PeterMortensen a sharp observation. They do capitalize the M though, so I wouldn't be apposed to the extra hyphen in the tag name because of that.

Comment: It seems worth noting that there are many software tools commonly described as "game makers" in a generic sense. If the tag is intended to refer to a specific one, something needs to be done to avoid that confusion. (The problem is even worse with "RPG makers", IMO.)